# Autocreate object when property is called

Tags: php

Im wondering if there is a way to autocreate object if a property is called. An example:

```
<?php
  echo $myObj->myProperty
?>
```

This code will of course fail because i did not initiate $myObj before reading the property.
What im looking for is a way to automaticly initiate $myObj based on "myObj".

Something like:

```
<?php
class myObj {
  public myProperty = 'BlaBla';
}
echo $myObj->myProperty; //outputs BlaBla instead of failing
?>
```

I know about __autoload($classname) but that only works of initiating classcode with i.e. an include(), so that is not what im after.

Comment: I can't think of any legitimate uses for this sort of thing. Why can't you just initialize the object before accessing the prop? (I'm assuming you have some specific need for it to be an instance and not a static accessor)

Comment: Its because I have a script that will eval() some content from the database. This content might include calls to objects that are not created yet. I could create all of the objects that *might* be needed, but why do that if they will not be needed. It will just take op CPU time and memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, this is what i ended up doing:

```
preg_match_all("/\\\$(.*?)->/si", $code, $matches);
```

I loop trough the code i get from database looking for any references to objects like

```
$xxxx->
```

Then i loop trough the references and create the objects

```
            foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
            $$value = Connector::loadConnector($value);
        }
```

Where the "loadConnector is:

```
    public function loadConnector($connector, $params = NULL) {
    require_once $connector. ".php";
    $c_name = $connector;
    return new $c_name($params);    
}
```

This is of course based on my file structure and it also needs some errorhandling, but so far it looks like it solves my problem :)

BR/Sune

Answer (score 1):

You can use magic methods to automate stuff like that...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Cant seem to figure out what magic method to use - could you guide me in right direction?